# Preventing Oracle data files from being used on other servers

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to encrypt or password protect Oracle database files so that they can not be used in case they were copied  to other servers?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out DBMS_CRYPTO and Transparent Data Encryption in 10g.

Answer (score 2):

Besides internal encryption, you can consider an encrypted filesystem, that only the "oracle" user has access to.

I could suggest a few but you didn't list the host operating system.

Comment: I am using Windows server so I can use EFS.
Thanks.